The difference between computed signal and getter in Angular
Signals is a cutting edge feature in Angular.
But the questions arouse what is the difference between
computed(() => `Result: ${this.someSignal()}`)

and
get someGetter () { return `Result: ${this.someSignal()}` }

First I thought that maybe getter won't be run when ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is selected but that's not the case.
Here is an example where the both are working just the same
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-s2epxq?file=src%2Fmain.ts
So what is the difference and should we really prefer one before another?

You're getter doesn't return a signal, it is not reactive.
Only reactive node will be part of the reactivity tree and help Angular understand where a value changes and which component is impacted by it.
Also computed values get memoized, they would not get re-executed until one of their producers becomes dirty.

Check the example, how is Angular understand that signalGetter is changed and re-renders its value?
What is the practical difference here?

okey, I added console log and it seems getter is called more often, thank you
I can accept your answer if you will make it more descriptive, with an example like I mentioned "getter is called more often because is called on every CD cycle"

Call you getter  from your template and you'll see that you'll probably get a NG0100

It doesn't cause any errors, but as I mentioned above, it is called on every cycle no matter if signal inside a getter was changed. I edited your answer with my example to make it more explanative and accepted it

I've added a mention of memoizing that happen with computed.
